# how to show a computed one2many field Odoo(api v8)

Tags: odoo

I want to know how to show a one2many computed field in a tree view, I tried the following code but without results:

```
@api.one
def _compute_o2m_field(self):
    related_recordset = self.env["product.product"].search([])
    self.productos = related_recordset

products = fields.One2many(string="products", compute='_compute_o2m_field')
```

any idea?,
thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
@api.one
def _compute_o2m_field(self):
    related_recordset = self.env["product.product"].search([])
    self.products = related_recordset.ids

products = fields.One2many('product.product','many2onefieldonproduct',string="products", compute='_compute_o2m_field')
```

Comment: fine, with "related_recordset.ids" I have a ids list of products, now, I want to make some calculations with product data and display them in a custom table, how I can show this table in a tree view, I tried: <field name="products" ><tree string="Products"><field name="name_template" /> </tree></field>, but it shows only the label and not the value of the field, maybe I can do this with Qweb templates??, thanks for answer

Answer (score 1):

**Computed Fields**

There is no more direct creation of fields.function.
Instead you add a compute kwarg. The value is the name of the function as a string or a function. This allows to
have fields definition atop of class

Your compute function should be like this,

```
@api.multi
def _compute_o2m_field(self):
    related_recordset = self.env["product.product"].search([])
    for obj in self:
        obj.products = related_recordset
```

**One2many**

Store a relation against many rows of co-model.

Specific options:

```
• comodel_name: name of the opposite model

• comodel_name: relational column of the opposite model
```

So, your field definition should be like this,

```
products = fields.One2many(comodel_name,comodel_name,string="products", compute='_compute_o2m_field')
```